# How to install Redmine on Fedora 11 linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, lamp, redmine, fedora11

I would like to install REDMine on my LINUX LAMP.
First i need to install ROR.

http://www.redmine.org

Provide steps if anybdoy has done installation

Answer (score 5):

If you actually looked, you would have found that the instructions are on the redmine website: http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineInstall

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your post, with details about your ruby installation, or installing the rails gem? What you have done so far, where it errors etc.

Answer (score 3):

Given that no truly reliable installation instructions can be found around (Fedora or other distribution that is), I will hereby detail the installation steps that worked for me. The website instructions are pretty reliable, but this is the most straightforward approach. I assume that you already have Apache2 and MySql, and installed Redmine 1.2.1 on a given $REDMINE_HOME.

This procedure was tested on Ubuntu 11.04, but given the packages involved, it should not be a problem replicating the procedure with success under Fedora. I will try to be as generic as possible.

**Ruby:**

1. Install ruby, rubygems, rake and the development mysql client library (libmysqlclient-dev on Ubuntu); a working ruby version is the 1.8.7 as of Sep '11
2. `gem install rails -v=2.3.11`
3. `gem install i18n -v=0.4.2`
4. `gem install mysql`

**MySql:**

Perform the following list of commands:

1. `create database redmine character set utf8;`
2. `create user 'redmine'@'localhost' identified by 'my_password';`
3. `grant all privileges on redmine.* to 'redmine'@'localhost';`

**Redmine configuration:**

1. Create a $REDMINE_HOME/config/database.yml file with at least the following profile:

   ```
   production:
     adapter: mysql
     database:  redmine
     host:  localhost
     username:  redmine
     password:  my_password
   ```
2. In $REDMINE_HOME, run

   - `rake generate_session_store`
   - `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`
   - `rake redmine:load_default_data RAILS_ENV=production`

Now running `ruby script/server -e production` should have you access Redmine at "0.0.0.0:3000".

**Apache2:**

1. Install the Apache2 Passenger mod (libapache2-mod-passenger in Ubuntu)
2. Assuming you provided a symbolic link to $REDMINE_HOME/public from /var/www/redmine, the virtual host should read something like this:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /var/www
       Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks    

       RailsBaseURI /redmine
       <Directory /var/www/redmine>
           Options -MultiViews
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

**Eclipse Mylyn integration:**

1. Go to $REDMINE_HOME/vendor/plugins and run

   `git clone git://redmin-mylyncon.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/redmin-mylyncon/redmine-mylyn-connector`
2. (Re)start the server, and in Redmine under Administration/Plugins the Mylyn Connector Plugin should be listed
3. Again in Redmine, under Administration/Settings/Authentication, check the "Enable REST web service" field
4. In Eclipse, install the Eclipse connector via its update site

   http://redmin-mylyncon.sourceforge.net/update-site/N/