# How to install redmine on amazon instance?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I am trying to install redmine on amazon instance. I have created a new user there and I removed ruby version 1.9.2p180 now it shows 
$ rails -v 
  Rails 2.3.5 
$ ruby -v 
bash: /usr/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory 
I think I want ruby 1.8.7 and less and rails 2.3 series to install redmine 
Please help me to install redmine.

Comment: What redmine version do you want to install? http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall lists the ruby and rails requirements per Redmine version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way to get Redmine up and running on EC2 is with a bitnami AMI. See [this website](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine#cloudImage). Just find the image in the AWS Console and fire it up.

Answer (score 1):

The installation instructions I provide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939914/how-to-install-redmine-on-fedora-11-linux/7427751#7427751) worked on a generic Ubuntu AMI. There should not really be any specific issue when dealing with an EC2 image.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Instance, use the following commands.

```
cd /usr/share/redmine/
mkdir tmp
chown www-data:www-data tmp
mkdir log
touch log/production.log
chown www-data:www-data log/production.log
sudo -u www-data X_DEBIAN_SITEID="default" ruby script/server webrick -e production
```

For more info,
    less /usr/share/doc/redmine/README.Debian.gz